# Igrouping does not find the right key for custom class

Tags: c#, igrouping

I have a custom class that contains 3 fields:

```
public class Selector
{
    public long? SubTypeID {get;set;}
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActionDate { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<IGrouping<Selector, Log>> query = src.GroupBy(td => new Selector() 
    {SubTypeID = td.SubTypeID, ActionDate = td.ActionDate, TypeID = td.ActivityTypeID}, 
    td => td);
```

When I have two logs that contain ActionDate = 'Sept 9, 2013' and SubTypeID = 3, and TypeID = 1, any idea why it might not group the two logs? Do I need to implement a custom compare? What is actually missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Selector, Log>> query` - this would be the use case for `var query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods within your `Selector` class. Otherwise standard reference comparison is being performed, and that's why your items are not grouped together.

You should also read [*Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)